# Why does C++ print small case alphabet when using std::hex and not capital?

Tags: c++, hex

The std::hex causes the data put into a stream to be printed as hexadecimal values. However, the letters A-F used to express number 10 to 15 always appear in small case alphabet. Is there a way to change it to use capital letters instead?

Comment: Use `std::uppercase`

Comment: @Ari0nhh That was easy to answer ;)

Comment: yes, that is because I am an electronic engineer and not used to this tool

Comment: @quantum231 _"that is because I am an electronic engineer"_ I'm admiring those people who are able to read these cryptic circuit plans for a whole chipset ;). Using references helps most of the time for c++, using datasheets and such is way harder (at least for me).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way to change it to use capital letters instead?

Yes, you can apply the [`std::uppercase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/uppercase) I/O manipulator to change the default behavior (which is lowercase).

The example from the reference mentioned above:

> > ```
> > #include <iostream>
> > int main()
> > {
> >     std::cout << std::hex << std::showbase
> >               << "0x2a with uppercase: " << std::uppercase << 0x2a << '\n'
> >               << "0x2a with nouppercase: " << std::nouppercase << 0x2a << '\n'
> >               << "1e-10 with uppercase: " << std::uppercase << 1e-10 << '\n'
> >               << "1e-10 with nouppercase: " << std::nouppercase << 1e-10 << '\n';
> > }
> > ```
> >
> > Output:
> >
> > ```
> > 0x2a with uppercase: 0X2A
> > 0x2a with nouppercase: 0x2a
> > 1e-10 with uppercase: 1E-10
> > 1e-10 with nouppercase: 1e-10
> > ```

Comment: I really needed this thing called showbase. The book have told me about std::hex which has brought a revolution into my life but never even mentioned std::uppercase or std::showbase. How very tragic. All those days of time I have lost will never come back.

Comment: @quantum231 Just use [en.cppreference.com], best reference you can have. Though you'll need to know where to look into. As mentioned I'm often lost in a similar way when trying to read a chips datasheet.